Casting points into line results in points out of order (sf in R)
I am trying to create a line out of a set of points in sf/R. When I try casting to a line the points are joined in an incorrect order. I have a variable I am using to sort my points, and it appears to be working correctly.
library(sf)
library(tidyverse) # for arrange
library(mapview)

pts <- structure(list(st_line_sample.st_cast.st_sfc.arrange.reaches..RM_End..geom... = structure(list(
    structure(c(1798845.54101626, 538707.519780606), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1798067.19669776, 541866.646974416
    ), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1798517.04773648, 
    546203.85324044), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(1797359.41988911, 552425.374682299), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1796822.89807808, 558767.884437151
    ), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1797350.84354281, 
    565185.350497763), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(1797514.3969019, 566904.386374215), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1799585.93763465, 572207.163585839
    ), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1799744.90644742, 
    576160.030206054), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(1800095.00638631, 578384.418665129), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1801403.41977244, 579875.968339903
    ), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1802554.23541705, 
    585558.341823224), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(1802555.85252448, 591135.320908832), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1803892.77204651, 595189.187151609
    ), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1804276.67076487, 
    596921.705731222), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(1805717.47532728, 603563.13179513), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOINT", "sfg")), structure(c(1810323.78904857, 612822.794823718
    ), dim = 1:2, class = c("XY", "MULTIPOINT", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    input = "NAD83(2011) / Washington North (ftUS)", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83(2011) / Washington North (ftUS)\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83(2011)\",\n        DATUM[\"NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",6318]],\n    CONVERSION[\"SPCS83 Washington North zone (US Survey feet)\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",47,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-120.833333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",48.7333333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",47.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",1640416.667,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"United States (USA) - Washington - counties of Chelan; Clallam; Douglas; Ferry; Grant north of approximately 47°30'N; Island; Jefferson; King; Kitsap; Lincoln; Okanogan; Pend Oreille; San Juan; Skagit; Snohomish; Spokane; Stevens; Whatcom.\"],\n        BBOX[47.08,-124.79,49.05,-117.02]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",6597]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 1796822.89807808, 
ymin = 538707.519780606, xmax = 1810323.78904857, ymax = 612822.794823718
), class = "bbox")), Reach.number = 1:17), row.names = c(NA, 
17L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "st_line_sample.st_cast.st_sfc.arrange.reaches..RM_End..geom...", agr = structure(c(Reach.number = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))

pts
# Simple feature collection with 17 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 1796823 ymin: 538707.5 xmax: 1810324 ymax: 612822.8
# Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / Washington North (ftUS)
# First 10 features:
#    st_line_sample.st_cast.st_sfc.arrange.reaches..RM_End..geom... Reach.number
# 1                                  MULTIPOINT ((1798846 538707...            1
# 2                                  MULTIPOINT ((1798067 541866...            2
# 3                                  MULTIPOINT ((1798517 546203...            3
# 4                                  MULTIPOINT ((1797359 552425...            4
# 5                                  MULTIPOINT ((1796823 558767...            5
# 6                                  MULTIPOINT ((1797351 565185...            6
# 7                                  MULTIPOINT ((1797514 566904...            7
# 8                                  MULTIPOINT ((1799586 572207...            8
# 9                                   MULTIPOINT ((1799745 576160))            9
# 10                                 MULTIPOINT ((1800095 578384...           10


line = pts |>
  arrange(Reach.number) |>
  mutate(river = "A") |>  # creating dummy variable to group_by
  group_by(river) |>
  summarize() |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
mapview(line) 



I've tried with and without the dummy variable, as well as moving the call to arrange immediately before the call to summarize() but nothing seems to affect the draw order.

I also tried stripping the points down using st_coordinates() which results in a 3 column matrix, that is in the correct order.  Arranging the points by the Y-coordinate, which also should set the correct order doesn't work

If you want to make a line from those points in the order of the data frame then:
myline = st_linestring(st_coordinates(pts))

does that, although you might then want to make an sfc object with the correct CRS:
> st_sfc(st_linestring(st_coordinates(pts)), crs=st_crs(pts))
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 1796823 ymin: 538707.5 xmax: 1810324 ymax: 612822.8
z_range:       zmin: 1 zmax: 17
Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / Washington North (ftUS)
LINESTRING Z (1798846 538707.5 1, 1798067 54186...

All your geometry objects are single points wrapped in a MULTIPOINT structure which simplifies things. Reorder the data frame by a column if you have another ordering.
Anything involving grouping will likely fail (as you see) or only work by coincidence. There's no guarantee of order preservation in the operations of a summarise.

This runs and plots using plot(myline) or ggplot(myline)+geom_sf(), and with the crs assigned, appears to be in the correct location (the ggplot version axes show in decimal degrees).  But if I try to use mapview(myline) I get a "mismatched geometry type error".  I can save as a geopackage layer, and subsequently open the layer in QGIS or read as new geometry in sf/R but mismatched geometry error persists.
